# Дополнение или придаточное изъяснительное?

Tags: пунктуация, спп, дополнение

Не пойму, чем является *во сколько* в этом предложении и нужна ли запятая?

> Василий мне звонил, сказал, что в субботу всех собирает, но не
>   сказал(,) во сколько.

Comment: Конечно, имею в виду БСП, которое аналогично СПП.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Василий мне звонил, сказал, (1) **что в субботу всех собирает**, но не сказал (2)  **во сколько.**

Это СПП с двумя придаточными изъяснительными, но второе придаточное состоит из одного союзного слова и не выделяется запятой.

В первом придаточном используется союз ЧТО. Опорные слова (сказуемые) у придаточных разные, между ними однородные отношения.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137
3) если придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия): Я бы тоже желал знать почему (Л. Т.);

Comment: @ Sharon, a где второе изъяснительное?

Comment: Оно состоит из одного слова (это неполное придаточное). Полный вариант:  не сказал, во сколько он всех собирает. Розенталь пишет: придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова

Answer (score 3):

> §107. Запятая между главным и придаточным предложениями... 
> **не** ставится 
>  
> в) если
>   придаточное предложение состоит из одного только союзного слова
>   *Мать температуру определяла губами: приложит губы ко лбу и сразу **определит сколько**.*

Розенталь Д.Э. и др. Справочник. ГЛАВА XXVIII
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm